# phpscheduleit mssql support

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

**How we configure and use phpscheduleit reservation and booking system with mssql ?
Please give an urgent solution.
It shows the following error after login.
**

```
MDB2_BufferedResult_mssql Object
```

(
    [db] => MDB2_Driver_mssql Object
        (
            [string_quoting] => Array
                (
                    [start] => '
                    [end] => '
                    [escape] => '
                    [escape_pattern] => 
                )

```
        [identifier_quoting] => Array
            (
                [start] => [
                [end] => ]
                [escape] => ]
            )

        [db_index] => 1
        [dsn] => Array
            (
                [phptype] => mssql
                [dbsyntax] => mssql
                [username] => cgvak
                [password] => cgvak
                [protocol] => 
                [hostspec] => 172.16.0.4
                [port] => 
                [socket] => 
                [database] => 
                [mode] => 
            )

        [connected_dsn] => Array
            (
                [phptype] => mssql
                [dbsyntax] => mssql
                [username] => cgvak
                [password] => cgvak
                [protocol] => 
                [hostspec] => 172.16.0.4
                [port] => 
                [socket] => 
                [database] => 
                [mode] => 
            )

        [connection] => Resource id #182
        [opened_persistent] => 1
        [database_name] => PhpScheduleIt
        [connected_database_name] => PhpScheduleIt
        [connected_server_info] => 
        [supported] => Array
            (
                [sequences] => emulated
                [indexes] => 1
                [affected_rows] => 1
                [summary_functions] => 1
                [order_by_text] => 1
                [transactions] => 1
                [savepoints] => 
                [current_id] => emulated
                [limit_queries] => emulated
                [LOBs] => 1
                [replace] => emulated
                [sub_selects] => 1
                [auto_increment] => 1
                [primary_key] => 1
                [result_introspection] => 1
                [prepared_statements] => emulated
                [identifier_quoting] => 
                [pattern_escaping] => 1
                [new_link] => 
            )

        [options] => Array
            (
                [ssl] => 
                [field_case] => 0
                [disable_query] => 
                [result_class] => MDB2_Result_%s
                [buffered_result_class] => MDB2_BufferedResult_%s
                [result_wrap_class] => 
                [result_buffering] => 1
                [fetch_class] => stdClass
                [persistent] => 1
                [debug] => 0
                [debug_handler] => MDB2_defaultDebugOutput
                [debug_expanded_output] => 
                [default_text_field_length] => 4096
                [lob_buffer_length] => 8192
                [log_line_break] => 

                [idxname_format] => %s_idx
                [seqname_format] => %s_seq
                [savepoint_format] => MDB2_SAVEPOINT_%s
                [statement_format] => MDB2_STATEMENT_%1$s_%2$s
                [seqcol_name] => sequence
                [quote_identifier] => 
                [use_transactions] => 1
                [decimal_places] => 2
                [portability] => 127
                [modules] => Array
                    (
                        [ex] => Extended
                        [dt] => Datatype
                        [mg] => Manager
                        [rv] => Reverse
                        [na] => Native
                        [fc] => Function
                    )

                [emulate_prepared] => 
                [datatype_map] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [datatype_map_callback] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [nativetype_map_callback] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [database_device] => 
                [database_size] => 
            )

        [sql_comments] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [start] => --
                        [end] => 

                        [escape] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [start] => /*
                        [end] => */
                        [escape] => 
                    )

            )

        [wildcards] => Array
            (
                [0] => %
                [1] => _
            )

        [as_keyword] =>  AS 
        [warnings] => Array
            (
            )

        [debug_output] => 
        [in_transaction] => 
        [nested_transaction_counter] => 
        [has_transaction_error] => 
        [offset] => 0
        [limit] => 0
        [phptype] => mssql
        [dbsyntax] => mssql
        [last_query] => SELECT user_id, password, salt, legacypassword
    FROM users 
    WHERE (username = 'admin@example.com' OR email = 'admin@example.com') AND status_id = 1
        [fetchmode] => 2
        [modules] => Array
            (
                [Datatype] => MDB2_Driver_Datatype_mssql Object
                    (
                        [valid_default_values] => Array
                            (
                                [text] => 
                                [boolean] => 1
                                [integer] => 0
                                [decimal] => 0
                                [float] => 0
                                [timestamp] => 1970-01-01 00:00:00
                                [time] => 00:00:00
                                [date] => 1970-01-01
                                [clob] => 
                                [blob] => 
                            )

                        [lobs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [db_index] => 1
                    )

            )

        [destructor_registered] => 1
        [_debug] => 
        [_default_error_mode] => 
        [_default_error_options] => 
        [_default_error_handler] => 
        [_error_class] => PEAR_Error
        [_expected_errors] => Array
            (
            )

        [datatype] => MDB2_Driver_Datatype_mssql Object
            (
                [valid_default_values] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => 
                        [boolean] => 1
                        [integer] => 0
                        [decimal] => 0
                        [float] => 0
                        [timestamp] => 1970-01-01 00:00:00
                        [time] => 00:00:00
                        [date] => 1970-01-01
                        [clob] => 
                        [blob] => 
                    )

                [lobs] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [db_index] => 1
            )

        [loaded_version_modules] => Array
            (
                [0] => datatype
            )

    )

[result] => Resource id #187
[rownum] => -1
[types] => Array
    (
    )

[values] => Array
    (
    )

[offset] => 0
[offset_count] => 0
[limit] => 0
[column_names] =>
```

)

error 01

Answer (score 0):

PHPScheduleIt is less supportive to mssql. You cannot make it plug and play with mssql, but its possible with some modifications in major sections.

Here is the link to their support forum. They can help you.

http://www.php.brickhost.com/forums/

Thanks,

Harry

http://innovativewebz.com/